# Question about the VTK XML StructuredGrid data file format

Tags: vtk, paraview

I am trying to output my numerical simulation data in vtk format.
My grid is structured and I need to use the VTK's XML format.
My greatest confusion is about the **WholeExtent** and the **Piece Extent** attributes.
E.g., the VTK pdf manual says

*StructuredGrid WholeExtent = "x1 x2 y1 y2 z1 z2"*.

What exactly are these `x1`, `x2`'s, etc? A similar question is about the `x1`, `x2`'s in the Piece Extent attribute.
Thank you!

Comment: As an answer was given on [VTK forum](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/extent-attributes-in-structuredgrid/7472), you may answer yourself here to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on [the VTK forum](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/extent-attributes-in-structuredgrid/7472), courtesy of Dan Lipsa.

It is easier to explain it using a minimum working example.
Suppose we have a 10x6x1 (2D) grid, 2 CPUs in the x-direction, 1 CPU in the remaining directions. That is, Proc 1 has 6x6x1 and Proc 2 has 5x6x1 grid points, respectively. Then I've these lines of code in my vts files:

Processor 1:
StructuredGrid WholeExtent=" 1 6 1 6 1 1 "
Piece Extent=" 1 6 1 6 1 1 "

Processor 2:
StructuredGrid WholeExtent=" 6 10 1 6 1 1 "
Piece Extent=" 6 10 1 6 1 1 "

A sample data file can be found at the following link:
[VTK forum](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/extent-attributes-in-structuredgrid/7472/4)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).